# Rails: Get "gem css_views" working for dynamic CSS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, css, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems

I'm tyring to use the GEM css_views to generate dynamic CSS.
The GEM can be found here: https://github.com/rhulse/rails-css-views

I've tried to follow the Readme, but removing the cache/minify things. However, I don't understand what parameters I'm supposed to give to "packaged_stylesheet_path" and "css_configuration".

Here is my code:

```
# app/controllers/style_controllers.rb
require 'css_views'

class StylesheetsController < ApplicationController
  include CssViews::ControllerMixins
  before_filter :set_vars

  css_configuration 'application', :components => ['user_css']

  private

  def set_vars
    @corp_black = '#310C04'
  end
end
```

-

```
#routes.rb
match '/stylesheets/:configuration_name(.:format)' => "stylesheets#show", :as=>:packaged_stylesheet
```

-

```
#app/views/layouts/application.html.erb
<head>
  <%= packaged_stylesheet_path('user_css', :css) %>
</head>
```

What 'im trying to do is use view/stylesheets/user_css.css.erb with variables.

Thanks for any tips :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you vooD for taking some time for helping me!

However, I've been lucky because I emailed the creator of css_views GEM and surprisingly, I did get a pretty fast answer. Very nice of him!
I'll share it with you since it answers my question (saying it won't provide a solution to my problem).

In the application layout you would use this:

```
production_stylesheet_path( 'application', '2011033101', :css )
```

The first param is what you want the name of the file to be, the second is a string for cache busting and the last is the file type. The above will generate:

```
/stylesheets/application-2011033101.css
```

'application' is which css_configuration to use. So the one above uses this one from my stylesheets controller:

```
css_configuration "application", :components=>['global', 'application', 'recipes', 'print'],:transformers=>[Transformer.new]
```

The components refer to the name of files in the /views/stylesheets folder, and the order to compile them in.

In development it'll serve up the files dynamically, but in production it will write out one file into /public/stylesheets/application-2011033101.css

This means that you can have variables in the css.erb files **BUT you cannot change them on a per request basis.**

If you update anything in the CSS erb files you have to bump the number, otherwise the changes may not appear, especially if you have far-future dates set for the headers on the CSS.

The Gem has been overtaken somewhat by stuff coming in Rails 3.1 - they are integrating SASS - but if you want a lighter weight solution, this is it!

I hope that all makes sense - let me know if you have any further questions!

Cheers,

Richard

Answer (score 0):

Looking into source code i see that you just need to pass an empty array as `:transformers` parameter

```
css_configuration 'application', :components => ['user_css'], :transformers => []
```